# Tensorflow equivalent of Theano's extra_ops.Unique

Tags: tensorflow, theano

How can I find the Tensorflow equivalent of Theano's `extra_ops.Unique` function?

```
tf.extra_ops.Unique(True, False, False)(la)[0].reshape([-1])
```

Comment: `extra_ops` is a submodule with a lot of different functions. Are you looking for a replacement of `Unique`, or for the whole `extra_ops`? If it's the latter, then you won't find an exact replacement in tensorflow.

Comment: I Want a replacement for Unique. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`tf.unique`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique).

- By default `tf.unique` returns a tuple `(unique_elements, idx)`. That corresponds to `theano.extra_ops.Unique(return_index=False, return_inverse=True, return_counts=False)`.
- If you need `return_counts=True`, then you should use [`tf.unique_with_counts`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique_with_counts), which corresponds to `theano.extra_ops.Unique(return_index=False, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)`
- `tf.unique` does not support the `return_index` argument that Theano (through [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)) supports, but you can reproduce that behavior with the following function (fetched on that [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4614#issuecomment-399732525)):

  ```
  def unique_with_inverse(x):
    y, idx = tf.unique(x)
    num_segments = tf.shape(y)[0]
    num_elems = tf.shape(x)[0]
    return (y, tf.math.unsorted_segment_min(tf.range(num_elems), idx, num_segments))
  ```

  This function would correspond to `theano.extra_ops.Unique(return_index=True, return_inverse=False, return_counts=False)`